# Run same executable multiple times in parallel

Tags: c++

I have an executable (e.g. test.exe) that is compiled c++/cli that can support multi threads. How can I run that same executable multiple times in parallel?
The easiest way is to open several cmd windows and run test.exe from there, but that's probably no the fastest or easiest way do it.

Comment: It's windows platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows you can use

```
start /B <executable>
```

This will run the process in the background, giving back a prompt, much like bash `&`

*--- EDIT ---*

And to run a predifined number of processes, you could use `FOR`:

```
FOR %i IN (1 2 3 4 5) DO start /B <executable>
```

Comment: B is nbr of threads?

Comment: @fmvpsenior Type `start /?` and see, or [read the documentation for `start`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Jason why don't you google police and join them

Comment: @fmvpsenior The cops don't have any jurisdiction here and it seems like a lot of training to go through just to tell you what everybody else already knows about [asking questions on the internet](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-the-Internet-and-Get-It-Answered).

Answer (score 1):

To run 15 instances simultaneously in a bourne compatible shell:

```
   for i in $(yes | sed 15q); do ./test.exe & done
```

Comment: it says "i was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @fmvpsenior Given that you stated you were using `cmd`, that would imply you are not using `bash`. Also note this answer is only relevant in an environment where `sed` is also installed.